# Simple model relationship question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have four rails models called user, school, subscription and news_item. I a situation where a user subscribes to school to get news notification from that school, how is it possible to display all the news_items that a user is subscribed to.

my user model has this

```
  belongs_to :school
  has_many :schools, :through => :subscriptions
  has_many :subscriptions

  def subscribe_to(school)
    subscribe = subscriptions.build(:school_id => school.id)
    if !subscribe.save
      logger.debug "you have already subscribed to '#{school.name}'"
    end
  end
```

after_create :create_school_subscription 
      def create_school_subscription
        school = self.school_street
        self.subscriptions.build(:school_id => school.id)
      end

and my subscription model has

```
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :school, :class_name => 'School'
  validates_uniqueness_of :school_id, :scope => :user_id
  validates_presence_of :user_id, :school_id
```

my school model has

```
  has_many :users
  has_many :news_items
```

finally my news_item model has

```
belongs_to :school
```

with all this put in place how can i get all the news a user is subscribed to through the school

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class NewsItem
  scope :news_for, lambda { |user|
    {
        :joins      => "INNER JOIN subscriptions on news_items.school_id = subscriptions.school_id",
        :conditions => "subscriptions.user_id = #{user.id}"
    }
  }
end

NewsItem.news_for(User.first)
```

Comment: this is the error: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'on news_items.school_street_id = subscriptions.school_id WHERE (subscriptions.us' at line 1: SELECT `news_items`.* FROM `news_items` subscriptions on news_items.school_id = subscriptions.school_id WHERE (subscriptions.user_id = 2)
`

Comment: Thank you very much i finally got it to work the way you specified.. But if i may ask is this approach better and faster than the first one?

Comment: This uses a single query, the other uses n+1 queries(so its faster). You can also use pagination with this to only fetch a subset of new_items like you do with any other query, with other you have to bake something of your own to do pagination.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the news items of all the schools of the user then:

```
usr.schools.map{|s| s.news_items}.flatten
```

If you want all the news items of only the school the user belongs to then:

```
usr.school.news_items
```

Good luck! :)

Comment: wow a very Good answer.. just tried it out and it works fine... so cool.. let me try the second answer

Comment: This would fire n+1 queries, if user has n schools. One to fetch user's schools and then 1 each for each school's news_items.